# Inline assembly on local array

Tags: arrays, gcc, assembly, inline, local

The inline assembly in the code below gives me segfault, cannot figure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(const int a[], int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d, ", a[i]);

  putchar('\n');

}


void myfunc() {
  int array[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

  printArray(array,10);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    asm volatile ("mov eax, [ebx+4*esi];"
          "lea eax, [eax+8*eax];"
          "mov [ebx+4*esi], eax"
          :  : "b" (array), "S" (i) : "memory", "eax");
  }

  printArray(array,10);
}

int main() {
  myfunc();
}
```

PS:

- It is the instruction "mov eax, [ebx+4*esi]" that causes segfualt.
- It is intel syntax, so you need to compile with -masm=intel option.
- It works fine when "array" is defined as a global variable.

Comment: Don't use inline assembly unless its your last resort. If it's for optimization, try the simple straightforward standard C code first, build with optimization, and measure to make sure it's not good enough (which often *is* good enough). If you feel you can create better code than the compiler (which is usually *not* the case) then look at what the compiler generated for your code (with optimizations enabled), and then try to beat it.

Comment: Are you compiling this as 32-bit or 64-bit? The code won't work as 64-bit given that you are treating the pointers as 32-bit values instead of 64-bit. Stack addresses in Linux can't be represented in a 32-bit value. Try using `-m32` as a GCC option or convert code to 64-bit.

Comment: @MichaelPetch
You are right. I forgot to use the -m32 option. 

Thanks a lot.